# In Assembler AT&T context: What does movl do in this specified line?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64

i have a some simple lines of code in C and wanted to disassemble it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int i=42;
}
```

After compiling it and starting gdb, i simply cant find my value=42 in the corresponding place:
[image]

Its not just that i get the value 0, but what exactly does

```
movl $0x2a, -0x4(%rbp)
```

mean. I know that 0x2a is 42 in hex, but the next part is cryptic to me; should it mean, that 42 gets saved into register rbp ? and what about the -0x4? And where is my 42 :O ?

Comment: `rbp-4` is the memory location on stack, corresponding to the `i` variable. But in general, this code should be optimized to simply `return 0`, as it is not doing anything

Comment: ok, i did return 0. I still can't access my 42, how to do it ?

Comment: You didn't understand what I said. Look here: https://godbolt.org/z/h664Kn5hr One is compiled with `-O0` (unoptimized) and is similar to your result. The other one is compiled with `-O3` (optimized) and it has nothing except the code corresponding to returning from the function.

Comment: You changed the title to just ask about the movl mnemonic, not the whole instruction.  It's a MOV with 32-bit (dword) operand-size.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov.   Is that all you wanted to know?  If not, that's not a useful title.  It looks from the question more likely you're asking about addressing-mode syntax for `-4(%rpb)`, i.e. Intel syntax `[rbp - 4]`.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Each variable in C either gets a set position in memory (called [the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))) or a [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register). In fact, the compiler will often move variables between these two places for performance.

`MOVL` moves a 32-bit number (your int!) from one register to another, while `MOV` moves an *entire* register, even if your program doesn't use that part of the register.

`PUSH` and `POP` add and remove items from the stack. It's often used by the C compiler to save registers. As a function calling `main()`, you have no idea what it does, and how to clean up after all the memory `main()` uses, which is why it is `main()`'s responsibility to clean up after itself, leaving the program exactly as it started with it. (except, of course, for the results of the operation)

`EAX` is a common register, and is typically used for the results of functions.

With this background, let's rewrite your program in a slightly more readable form:

1. `push %rbp` **Move** the stack pointer to the stack itself (so we can clean up after all of our junk memory)
2. `mov %rsp, %rbp` **Resize** the stack to `0`, **Preventing** the `main()` from accidentally reading junk from *other* functions
3. `movl $0x2a, -0x4(%rbp)` **Move** `42` to the first slot in the stack (note: Since an int is 4 bytes big, this is actually the -4th space!)
4. **Wait--** We never actually resized the stack to  tell other programs that our special number is there. This is because the compiler optimized it away, as it saw that we were increasing the size when we were going to reset it in a few instructions anyways.

   - Thank you Peter Cordes, for reminding me the [Red Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_%28computing%29) exists! This is a special area of memory inside of the stack which does not require the stack to be expanded before writing to it. In the case of this program, this is likely what is happening.
5. `MOV $0x0, %eax` **Move** `0` to the result register (`EAX`)
6. `POP %RBP` **Clean Up** after our mess by restoring the old stack pointer. This means that, even though we reset the size of the stack, the program above us will still have all of their memory intact. Remember--We did this to prevent `main()` from accessing other function's memory. Great!
7. `RETQ` **Return** and say goodbye ;(

If you wanted to retrieve your `42`, you would need to change your code to say `return 42`, which would means the compiler would place `42` in `EAX`, and it would get passed up to your friends above :)

Comment: ahhh ok i get it! That helped a lot! But one question remains:  mov %rsp, %rbp is moving the stack pointer away from the stack addressed as a whole register ? Thanks anyways buddy :)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. %RSP is the current stack pointer, and says where the next empty spot in the stack is in memory, while %RBP is the stack base, or where the stack "starts". The difference between RSP and RBP is the amount of stack currently in use by the function. Each function will set it's stack base to its stack pointer:

Moving RSP to RBP says, "From my point of view, the stack is empty, and I will not override any other function's critical data".

Comment: *while MOV moves an entire register, even if your program doesn't use that part of the register.*  No, `mov` without a suffix infers the operand-size from one of the operands being a register.  `mov $imm, mem` has no register, so it would be ambiguous without a suffix.  Yes, the `mov %rsp, %rbp` in this disassembly output is doing a 64-bit operand-size copy of a full register, i.e. `movq %rsp, %rbp` if you wanted to be explicit.  But `mov $1, %cl` is 8-bit operand-size, could be written as `movb $1, %cl`.

Comment: And the `mov $0, %eax` is a `movl`.  The destination is a 32-bit register which implies 32-bit operand-size in the machine code for `mov`.  And writing a 32-bit register does *implicitly* zero-extend to the full register.  But `mov %ecx, %edx` would only copy the low 32 bits of RCX so the value in RDX is truncated.  Not a full register copy like your phrasing implies.  And `mov %eax, -4(%rbp)` would only be a 4-byte store, not 8-byte full register.

Comment: TL:DR: the reason for an explicit operand-size is that `$imm, mem` would be ambiguous, that's all.  No difference between writing it as `mov` or `movl` when one or more operand is a register.  The disassembler just omits a suffix when it would be redundant.

Comment: Also: *This is because the compiler optimized it away, as it saw that we were increasing the size when we were going to reset it in a few instructions anyways.* - yes, but also because the x86-64 System V ABI guarantees a "red zone" that won't be stepped on asynchronously by signal handlers or anything else.  Without that, it wouldn't be safe, which is why compilers *don't* do that for Windows x64, or for 32-bit code.  (Which don't have a red-zone as part of the calling-convention / ABI)

Comment: Very well worded. Thank you for your time! (I had also completely forgotten about the red zone... edited answer to include.)